# Unity->AndroidStudioでreleaseビルドすると「Error: MethodHandle.invoke and MethodHandle.invokeExact are only〜」でapkが出力できない

Tags: unity3d, android-studio, firebase, gradle, admob

### 環境

Unity2017.4.10f1
Admob： Google Mobile Ads Unity Plugin v3.15.1 （最新版）
AppLovin： GoogleMobileAdsAppLovinMediation-4.0.0.zip （最新版）

### 内容

上記環境で、gradleビルドで、ExportしたものをAndroidStudio上で、build.gradleやManifestを適宜修正し。

debug用のapkまでは問題なく出力できるようになりました。
ただ、release用のapkを出力しようとした場合に。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このエラーになりました。

```
Error: MethodHandle.invoke and MethodHandle.invokeExact are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

エラー内容どおり、minSdkVersionを26にすれば成功しますが、、
Android 8.0 以上と限定されてしまうため、せめてminSdkVersionを19以上にしたいのですが、
方法はないでしょうか？

（debugでapkファイルを出力した場合はAndroidOS7.0の端末でも問題なくアプリが動くので、
何か解決策がないか色々調べましたが見つからずお力添えいただければ幸いです泣）

#### 試したこと

- unity上で直接ビルドできないか、internalやgradleビルド、custom gradle template等
- SDK,JDK,NDKのバージョンアップを色々と変更して試してみました。
- build.gradleのmavenやgradleバージョン調整、groovy:groovy-allを入れたりなどなど
- もしかして、Unity上で、`Invoke()`メソッドを使ってしまっているのが原因？

Answer (score 1):

見て頂いた方大変失礼しました！

> もしかして、Unity上で、Invoke()メソッドを使ってしまっているのが原因？

こちら実際にInvoke()メソッドをすべてcoroutineに置き換えてビルドし直したところ、
無事minSdkVersion 19でもビルドできました！！！（ToT）

NGUIライブラリ内でもInvoke（）メソッドを使っており、念の為こちらもコメントアウトして対応しました。。（泣）